# filling a dictionary of counts from an iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the most pythonic way to fill a dictionary of counts from an iterable?

I know that there is `collections.Counter`, with which I can do

```
counter = Counter(iterable)
```

and then use `counter` just like a dictionary having as keys the distinct items of `iterable` and as values their counts.

But there must be a pythonic way of doing the same thing with a regular `dict`, something more compact than

```
count = {}
for item in iterable:
    if item not in count:
        count[item] = 1
    else:
        count[item] += 1
```

What is it?

Comment: You could use `.get` with a `0` default, but normally one would just use a counter. That's exactly what it's for.

Comment: Using `collections.Counter` is the most Pythonic way. Maybe not the most efficient which I doubt so but it's definitely the most Pythonic.

Comment: @Kasrâmvd why wouldn't it be the most efficient?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Because I'm not fully aware of the internal implementation of the `collections.Counter` and also because it's the magnificent Python land with a lot of hidden Easter Eggs :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One simple way:

```
count = {}
for item in iterable:
    count[item] = count.get(item, 0) + 1
```

But generally, you should just use a `collections.Counter`. You don't use a `Counter` "just like" a dict, it *is a* dict.